Why I'm getting URI not registered in jetified-play-services-ads-lite?
Good day all, recently i updated firebase-ads in build.gradle to 22.0.0 from 20.6.0 since the old version is already sunset.
After updating to newer version I'm getting URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs) in jetified-play-services-ads-lite-22.6.0\AndroidManifest.xml followed by multiple errors in same file (See attached picture). I'm stuck here now, downgrading to lower version is not accepeted by Google Play Team.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:22.0.0' // previous version  20.6.0



I found a temporary solution in Github
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/issues/2930
Solution was to update to 22.3.0 which is still compliant with google play console requirement.

So I updated version of firebase-ads as shown below.
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:22.3.0'

